# How to update random rows?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I update random rows in a table ?

I have just tired the flowing query but it updated a full table.

```
UPDATE Table SET Flag = 1
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT TOP 5000 *
FROM Table
ORDER BY newid()
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work I think:

```
UPDATE Table
SET Flag = 1
FROM Table t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT TOP 5000 *
    FROM Table 
   ORDER BY NewID()
) t2 on t2.id = t1.id
```